# VisualStateManager and MVVM

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, visualstatemanager

I'm working on a Windows 8 Store App (using the Grid App Template) and while I'm loading data from a server I want to show a `ProgressRing` and hide the `GridView` or `ListView` (depends on if the app is snapped or not) that will display the data once it is fully loaded.

The issue is that when the ViewModel is loading data I need to be able to change the VisualState.

I found what I thought was a solution [Here](http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/using-the-visualstatemanager-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern-in-wpf-or-silverlight/#comment-38), but this code will not build.

```
public class StateManager : DependencyObject
{
    public static string GetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetVisualStateProperty(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisualStatePropertyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStatePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "VisualStateProperty",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(StateManager),
        new PropertyMetadata((s, e) =>  //this throws the error
        {
        var propertyName = (string)e.NewValue;
        var ctrl = s as Control;
        if (ctrl == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This attached property only supports types derived from Control.");
        System.Windows.VisualStateManager.GoToState(ctrl, (string)e.NewValue, true);
    }));
}
```

> ERROR: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is
>   not a delegate type

Does anyone know how to get the linked solution to work?  Or is there a simpler method that I am completely missing (I'm a XAML newbie!)?

I'm not even sure if the listed solution will work because the "Snapped" vs "Full" states are managed by the base `LayoutAwarePage` class included with the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not simply use a datatrigger bind to a viewmodel property like IsBusy {get;set;} to enable your Progressring?

Comment: I actually have a IsBusy Property and tried that, but the issue is that my data start to show up on the screen (incomplete) while the progress wheel is still loading.  I want the Item Views to be invisible until all the data is loaded (as I am typing this I am being to think that's a silly idea, and I should just load the data in a way that is still helpful when incomplete)

Comment: the datatrigger can also handle the visibility for your item views.